# Get Value For A Specific Cell From A CSV By Convert To XLS Spreadsheet Java

Tags: java, csv

So I'm trying to build a program that takes a CSV file and returns the values of some specific cells. I want this program to be able to handle similar but different CSV spreadsheets, meaning the data that needs to be grabbed will always be there, but the column/row coordinates may be different. Here's what I have, though I have a feeling I should start over:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSV {

private static HashMap<Point, String> _map = new HashMap<Point, String>();
private int _cols;
private int _rows;

public void open(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    open(file, ',');
}

public void open(File file, char delimiter)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    scanner.useDelimiter(Character.toString(delimiter));

    clear();

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] values = scanner.nextLine().split(Character.toString(delimiter));

        int col = 0;
        for ( String value: values ) {
            _map.put(new Point(col, _rows), value);
            _cols = Math.max(_cols, ++col);
        }
        _rows++;
    }
    scanner.close();
}

public void save(File file) throws IOException {
    save(file, ',');
}

public void save(File file, char delimiter) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    for (int row = 0; row < _rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < _cols; col++) {
            Point key = new Point(col, row);
            if (_map.containsKey(key)) {
                bw.write(_map.get(key));
            }

            if ((col + 1) < _cols) {
                bw.write(delimiter);
            }
        }
        bw.newLine();
    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}

public static String get(int col, int row) {
    String val = "";
    Point key = new Point(col, row);
    if (_map.containsKey(key)) {
        val = _map.get(key);
    }
    return val;
}


public void put(int col, int row, String value) {
    _map.put(new Point(col, row), value);
    _cols = Math.max(_cols, col+1);
    _rows = Math.max(_rows, row+1);
}

public void clear() {
    _map.clear();
    _cols = 0;
    _rows = 0;
}

public int rows() {
    return _rows;
}

public int cols() {
    return _cols;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        CSV csv = new CSV();

        csv.open(new File("mycsv.csv"));
        System.out.println(get(1,1));

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

My original idea was to use a "for" loop that just goes through that get() function until I found the right row where the data should be (far left of the spreadsheet is labeled with words).

```
public static String getStreamTW(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++){
        if(CSV.get(0,i)=="Audio"){
            return(CSV.get(1,i));
        }
    }
    return "N/A";
}
```

And yeah that just doesn't work and sometimes the data gets all cut up so I don't think that's any good. What do you all think? Is there anything out there that can get data by cell? Think the formatting is getting all messed up so I wanna deal with this by cells. I was thinking of converting the CSV to an excel spreadsheet and then working from there. Is that a good idea/do you all have some resources for that?

Comment: Can you expand on "And yeah that just doesn't work and sometimes the data gets all cut up so I don't think thats any good"?  What goes wrong?  The only thing that jumps out at me is that you might run into trouble with `String.split` if the rows contain escaped commas, but that doesn't seem like it should cause you trouble with the situation you're describing.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury that for loop just doesn't work. The data is definitely there but it always comes up as "N/A." Also, the data entry is usually one big number such as "3212256" but sometimes when I call that specific entry (for example, CSV.get(1,20)) it will split that number up like "3212 with only one quote.

Comment: Why are you using a Scanner for reading here and what happens when you both set a delimiter on the scanner object and do split() on the string returned by nextLine(). I don't know if this causes a problem but it looks strange. Why not use BufferedReader with readLine() instead?